# What do you think of my regex for URL validation?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I would like you to review my regex.  It's suppose to recognize common URLs like:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.sub1.sub2.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://www.google.com/path1/path2
http://www.google.com/path1/path2/
http://www.google.com/path1/path2/a=b&c=d
http://www.google.com/path1/path2/a=b&c=d/

var url = new RegExp("^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[-a-z0-9]+(?:(?:(?:\/[-=&?.#a-z0-9]+)+)\/?)?$");
```

Answer (score 15):

Your regex has many false positives (matches without a valid URL being there), and many false negativs (URLs you don't recognize). You should read the appropriate RFCs which contain relevant parts of the grammar.

Here are some failure scenarios:

- ⊖ You don't match schemes other than HTTP or HTTPS. Consider FTP, SFTP, data URLs, and other widespread schemes like `file:`, `mailto:`, `irc:` or `skype:`. Consider also that the scheme is sometimes omitted, so that the same protocol as the current document is assumed. Test cases:

  ```
  ftp://example.com/
  data:text/html,<p>Hello World!
  mailto:foo@example.com
  //example.com/
  ```

  Every scheme has a slightly different syntax, so you'll have to decide which ones you support. Note that matching a HTTP(S) URL is different from matching all URLs.
- ⊕ You match some domain names that are syntactically correct, but *semantically* only consist of a top level domain. You may or may not wish to rule these out:

  ```
  http://co.uk/
  ```

  See the [Mozilla Public Suffix List](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) for the only reliable way to do this.
- ⊖ Some host names don't have a TLD:

  ```
  http://localhost/
  ```
- ⊕ You match loads of stuff that isn't ok, e.g.:

  ```
  999.999.999.999/this-is-no-ip4-address
  -.-
  ```
- ⊖ You don't have support for ports:

  ```
  http://example.com:80/
  ```
- ⊖ You don't have support for IPv6 IPs.

  ```
  http://::1/
  http://[::1]:80/
  ```
- ⊖ You can't match any authority in the host part:

  ```
  ftp://user:password@example.com/
  ```
- ⊖ You don't support URL-encoding:

  ```
  http://example.com/some%20path
  ```
- ⊖ You don't support Unicode chars:

  ```
  http://example.com/smørrebrød/greek-Λεττερς
  ```

  Consider also that the host name may contain Unicode characters, but will have an equivalent punycode representation.
- ⊖ Coming to think of it, you actually forbid quite a lot of (special) characters, although they would be perfectly valid (the host part is more restricted).

  ```
  http://example.com/stuff_(in parens)/
  ```
- ⊖ In a URL, the path is followed by a single query string, introduced by a `?`. Note that the semicolon `;` is the more modern, but equivalent alternative to the `&` separator. The `+` means a literal space here. The query string may only be followed by a fragment, which is separated by `#`. Other instances have to be encoded.

---

For an overview of URL syntax, start with this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). Also look at [URI Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). These articles also link to relevant specs.

Answer (score 3):

**As an addentum to @amon's excellent answer:**

The *Expression Library* of the *Expresso* RegEx tool has this pattern for URL's (C# syntax):

```
(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*
```

Putting it against @amon's test cases yields these results:

[image: url regex validation]

Stuff in parentheses isn't captured, nor IPV6 IP's. But I'd consider it a good **starting point** with fewer false positives, and it also matches all the common URL's in this question.

Now your pattern doesn't match *any* of the URL's I've tested with that tool, and the above regex pattern certainly wouldn't work in JavaScript. Removing the named capture groups gives this (untested):

```
\w+:\/\/[\w@][\w.:@]+\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*
```

#### Some ideas:

- Use numbered **capture groups** to distinguish the URL parts. It makes it a little easier to debug a regular expression that doesn't do what it's supposed to be doing.
- Depending on how the result is used, I would also add a group that captures the **query string** independently, if the URL has one.